# selinux, Avc issue after giving permission

Tags: android, selinux

I am getting avc denial issue after giving permission. Error message:

> avc: denied { transition } for pid=189 comm="init"
>   path="/system/bin/androlircd" dev="mmcblk0p9" ino=145
>   scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:lircd_exec:s0 tclass=process

I have given transition permission in init.te as :

```
type_transition init lircd_exec:process lircd;
allow init lircd_exec:file execute;
allow init lircd:process transition;
```

after giving permission also the issue is happening.
Is there any way to solve this. please help.

my androlircd service is as :

```
service androlircd /system/bin/androlircd   
class core   
user root  
group root system system  
seclabel u:object_r:lircd_exec:s0 
oneshot
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it corrected.
I need to assign selinux labels for the device node that was created,in device.te file. Label for the androlircd service in service.te and edited the service as

```
service androlircd /system/bin/androlircd   
class main  
oneshot
```

Policies were written as required.